# Javascript - Previous month computation from a current date

Tags: javascript

I have a below JS where I get the max date that is user allowed to enter from a backend script:

```
var max_date = new Date(pdate + " " + ptime);
```

where pdate and ptime is fetched from a script.

Now I need to set the min date as 1 month less than max_date

```
if (max_date.getMonth() == 0)
subtractyear = 1;
var min_date = new Date(Date.UTC(max_date.getFullYear() - subtractyear,max_date.getMonth() - 1,max_date.getDate(),max_date.getHours(),0,0));
```

My issue is that if max_date is March 31 - then will the min_date be rolled over to Feb 28 or Feb 29 or Feb 31 or Feb 30?

If the date formed is an incorrect date - say Feb 30 how can I rectify this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple subject the month by 1 would get a valid date -- never would `setMonth` method return an invalid `Date` object (the same as `setDate`, `setYear` and the `Date` constructor):

```
var date = new Date(2012, 02, 31); // 2012-03-31
date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1); // This gets 2012-03-02
```

I don't quite clear what date you expected, **the last day of the previous month** or just **the day one month earlier**?

Comment: Thanks. I need a date 30 days prior to max_date. So if max_date is March 31 then minimum date user can input is Feb 28 (if not leap year) else Feb 29th or accordingly 1 month less than max_date? I understand that it would then always calculate the correct date

Comment: Simply try `date.setDate(date.getDate() - 30)` would get the expected result

Comment: I have 2 dates for user input - max_date and min_date both of which I need - the min_date should be 1 month less than max_date. So will min_date.setDate(max_date.getDate() - 30) work? So var min_date = new Date(Date.UTC(max_date.getFullYear() - subtractyear,max_date.getMonth() - 1,max_date.getDate(),max_date.getHours(),0,0)); will be correct date if max_date is March 31st?

Comment: Try `min_date < max_date.setDate(max_date.getDate() - 30)`, it evaluates `true` when `min_date` is 31 days or more earlier than `max_date`, use `<=` if you wanna include a date exactly **30** days earlier than `max_date`

Comment: What if the month is January. This won't work. Or will it work?

Comment: This solution will not work in January case. `date` will return `Invalid date`.